# Point of tangency between given linear equation and circle equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, circles, tangent-line

I'm trying to find the point of tangency between the circle $ (x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2=25 $ and the linear equation $ y = -0.75x + 3.125 $ as seen on the graph.

[image: Graph]

In the image I attached I used trial and error to get the approximate point of tangency between the linear curve and the circle which is almost at $ 18.75 = 25-(x-3)^2 - (y-4)^2 $

Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm trying to find the tangency point a circle shaped utility function and a a budget restriction (linear equation) for a micro economics class.

Comment: Fix the equation of the circle and can you provide additional context to the question? Is this a question from the chapter you have studied? What difficulty are you facing in solving the problem?

Comment: The corrected equation: $(x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=25$ and $y=-0.75x+3.125$ do not touch each other (they actually cut).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction of the gradient vector at the point of tangency should be the same as the direction of normal to the circle.

The gradient vector is $$ <2(x-3),2(y-4)>$$ and the slope of the normal vector is the opposite reciprocal of the slope of the tangent line.

That is $$\frac {y-4}{x-3} = 4/3$$
The  above equation implies $$y=(4/3)x$$
Plug in the equation of the given line, $$ y=-.75x+3.125$$
We get the point of tangency to be $$(x,y)= (1.5,2)$$ as indicated by the graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! This is exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe how simple it was

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$
\cases{
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2 = r^2\\
a x + b y = c
}
$$

after substitution we have

$$
(x-x_0)^2+((c-a x)/b -y_0)^2= r^2
$$

and then the solution is at

$$
x = \frac{b \left(b x_0\pm \sqrt{r^2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)-(a x_0+b y_9-c)^2}\right)+a (c-b
   y_0)}{a^2+b^2}
$$

now, at tangency $x$ should be unique thus

$$
r^2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)-(a x_0+b y_9-c)^2 = 0
$$

and solving for $c$ it gives

$$
c = \pm r \sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2\right)}+a x_0+b y_0
$$